# How to open a Html as a Help file in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a help in Html to attach to my project. My project has been developed in WPF.

But may I add the Html as a resource to the project or I just put the folder with my Html and the images I am using in it in the Project folder?

If the second option is better than the first, how can I get the Path to my Html file?

Anyway I will create an installer to my App, I will use the installer from Visual Studio but when I do it, how I can make sure that he will open the Html successfully?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with the second option and just have the file in the project (make sure to right-click->properties and turn on "copy to ouput directory").

You can use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control to render the html.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`  gets you the directory containing the application.

**XAML**:

```
<WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1"/>
```

**Code Behind**:

```
var filename = "help.html";
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, filename);      
webBrowser1.Navigate(path);
```